# How can I speed up below program's execution?

Tags: java, apache, file, mahout, mahout-recommender

Below is the code for user recommendations using mahout.

```
DataModel dm = new FileDataModel(new File(inputFile));
UserSimilarity sim = new LogLikelihoodSimilarity(dm);
UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new NearestNUserNeighborhood(100, sim,
            dm);
GenericUserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(
            dm, neighborhood, sim);
```

After the recommendations are generated, I am trying to write it to a file as below:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile);
for (LongPrimitiveIterator userIterator = dm.getItemIDs(); userIterator.hasNext();) {
long user = (long) userIterator.next();
List<RecommendedItem> recs = recommender.recommend(user, numOfRec );
        for (RecommendedItem item : recs) {
            writer.write(user + "," + item.getItemID() + ","
                    + item.getValue()+"\n");
        }
    }
writer.close();
```

This code - to write to file, is taking lot of time. How can I spped up the write operations?

Comment: Reduce the amount of final data your  fwriter has to process by using conditionals/filters etc.

Comment: @TheLaw, can you give example of conditionals/filters ?

Comment: Do not use `String` concatenation with `+`, but use distinct `write` calls instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JordiCastilla, I am moving the question to codereview section.

Comment: @dhirajforyou well done, you will have a better and faster answer there if your code is working.

Comment: @all, update: I tried with buffered writer, but still takes more than 28 minutes to write 270000 lines.

Comment: Please check the same question on code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/110246

Answer (score 0):

I see few potential improvements that you can make:

1. Use BufferedWriter instead of plain writer. It should safe you something around 30% but just on plain writing time. It should be around few hundred ms for 100k lines.

   ```
   Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
   ```
2. Write recommend processing and writing to file in two separate threads that one don't have to wait for the other.
3. Extending point 2, you can try pack recommending processing into the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Right now your code is one thread only and most current processor has much more cores than can be used for that. Let me know if you need more info on that.

Comment: I tried with BufferedWriter, but in vain.
I am trying for parallel threads and will update if succeeds.

Comment: Writing is not a problem here. To write 100k lines it took something around 100ms on my laptop. You need to optimise handling of recommender. Try with the pool executor.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marek. As you said, I am able to write junk stings  to a file 1000K within a minute. I am trying the same with parallel  threads and will get back if succeeds.